# Website hosted by IIS doesn't support VB 14 new features?

Tags: vb.net, iis-7.5

I'm trying [Read-only auto-properties](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-VB-14#read-only-auto-properties) today. VS2015 doesn't complain about the new syntax, but when I view the page in browser it shows error "BC36714: Expanded Properties cannot be initialized."

Do I forget to set anything?

[image: VS2015 doesn't complain about the new syntax]

[image: when I view the page in browser it shows error "BC36714: Expanded Properties cannot be initialized."]

**Update:**

`Public ReadOnly Property Tags As New List(Of String)` causes the same compilation error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my VS2015 Pro update 2, with .NET 4.6 - The only thing i can think of is that it is a bug that may be fixed in that update.